# grep nmap output, conditionally print selected lines

Tags: linux, bash, grep, nmap

I am trying to write a bash script which will read through a series of ip addresses in a .txt file and will execute a nmap scan on each single ip with a NSE ([`smb-os-discovery`](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/smb-os-discovery.html)) script with it.  From this output I would like to print only certain lines, but only if one of them matches a specific pattern.

I have tried multiple different options but just can't get it to work as I want it, given that the two items I want to check and output are in two different lines.
The closest I managed to get was by writing the below bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for server in $(cat servers-smb.txt); do
nmap --script smb-os-discovery $server | grep "report\|OS: Windows"
done
```

When running the above script the output has the servers running Windows but also the `report` line for the ones which don't, which is expected since the grep expression contains an 'OR' operator.

Any help with this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If your main problem is figuring out a better `grep` expression, please post some sample output from your `nmap` command that we can work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`grep` does not easily adapt to what you want, but Awk is a natural fit.

```
#!/bin/sh
while read server; do
   nmap --script smb-os-discovery "$server" |
    awk '/report/ { r=$0 } /OS: Windows/ { print r; print; exit }'
done <servers-smb.txt
```

The Awk script collects the report line, then prints it along with the OS: line if it matches "OS: Windows".

Note also the changed shebang (there is nothing Bash-specific in this script, so might as well run it with plain `sh`), the preference of `while` over `for` + [Useless `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html), proper quoting of `"$server"` inside the loop, and finally the use of proper indentation inside a control block for legibility.

A less attractive approach would be to string two `grep`s.  I'm mentioning it here for completeness -- anything with more than one `grep` is probably better done as an Awk or `sed` script.

```
grep "report\|OS: Windows" | grep -B1 "OS: Windows"
```

Finally, a simple way to achieve the same result with just `grep` is to massage the IP address into the output, as you already have it in the `server` variable.

```
while read server; do
    nmap --script smb-os-discovery "$server" |
    # XXX: suboptimal; see below
    grep "OS: Windows" | sed "s/^/$server:/"
done <servers-smb.txt
```

but of course, `grep | sed` is also an antipattern, and is better expressed as just a `sed` script:

```
while read server; do
    nmap --script smb-os-discovery "$server" |
    sed -n "/OS: Windows/s/^/$server:/p"
done <servers-smb.txt
```

This has the additional benefit of collecting the output for one host on one line, which makes it better suited for additional processing with typical Unix line-oriented tools.